# Downloading LIDAR from The National Map

Tags: geospatial, download, usgs

I have found the .las file I'm looking for of Mill Basin, Brooklyn, NYC... USGS Lidar Point Cloud NY CMPG 2013 18TWK910955 LAS 2015.

I navigate to the area of interest, create my bounding box, search for LiDAR files, locate the file, click "Download ZIP" and the Download link opens a new tab but never downloads anything.

Are others experiencing this same issue? What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check this out if you have not seen this. I google and found this site that might be useful for you...  https://gis.ny.gov/elevation/lidar-coverage.htm

Just remember that these LIDAR files can be very large to download it....